# pdfError, font not found cmtt10

Tags: beamer, fonts

I'm a newbie in latex and i'm using "pdflatex" on this code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{JuanLesPins}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Apoyo para el estudiante universitario}  
\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
Clases individuales de:
\begin{itemize}
\item Análisis Matemático 1 y 2
\item Álgebra
\item Física y Biofísica
\item Química
\item Programación
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
Universidades:
\begin{itemize}
\item \bfseries{UBA}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Económicas
  \item Ingenieria
  \item Arquitectura
  \item Medicina
  \item CBC
  \end{itemize}
\item\bfseries{UTN}  
\item \bfseries{UADE}
\item \bfseries{UCA}
\item \bfseries{Kennedy}
\end{itemize}
Otras universidades
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\begin{center}
Contacto: \verb|15-6566-0466 4863-3135|  Almagro.
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

and i have this error:
```

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file cmtt10): Font cmtt10 at 657 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

i already did:

```
sudo dnf install 'tex(cmtt10.tfm)'
```

but the error is still there, any suggestion, please?

Comment: Sounds as if there is some problem with your tex installation. Which version do you have?

Comment: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)

Comment: to include the font in your pdf file, you need the type1 file with the definitions of the character shapes.  that *should* be present in a usual installation of tex live, unless you explicitly failed to load the fonts.

Comment: What happens if you add `\pdfmapfile{=cm.map}` to your document?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer now it' fix, but without accents :(, but thanks

Comment: You need inputenc for accents.

Comment: You should report this to Fedora. Installation of the package should trigger the steps necessary to register the `.map` file fragment. If just adding that line resolves the problem, there's a packaging bug.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you like to convert you comment into an answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments